# How to generate authentication credentials for Google Sheets API?

Tags: google-sheets-api

Step 1 (completed):

As instructed, I have followed every step in Google's Node.js Quickstart:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs
and it ran perfectly without any errors. My understanding was that after I run index.js, a token.json is created. After which, I can somehow use the token.json for any future authentication purpose without needing credentials.json every time. Please, correct me if I am wrong in this assumption. I am only making this assumption based on what Google is saying in the previously given link - "Authorization information is stored on the file system, so subsequent executions will not prompt for authorization."

Step 2 (problem):

Below is another code snippet is given by a Google Sheet's API's documentation page for reading multiple range data:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet

I, however, do not know how to generate authentication credentials for authClient. Am I suppose to do something with token.json? If yes, what is the protocol of using the token.json file?

Please feel free to ask any follow-up questions if needed.

```
  enter code here// BEFORE RUNNING:
    // ---------------
    // 1. If not already done, enable the Google Sheets API
    //    and check the quota for your project at
    //    https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sheets
    // 2. Install the Node.js client library by running
    //    `npm install googleapis --save`

    const {google} = require('googleapis');
    var sheets = google.sheets('v4');

    authorize(function(authClient) {
      var request = {
        // The ID of the spreadsheet to retrieve data from.
        spreadsheetId: 'my-spreadsheet-id',  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

        // The A1 notation of the values to retrieve.
        ranges: [],  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

        // How values should be represented in the output.
        // The default render option is ValueRenderOption.FORMATTED_VALUE.
        valueRenderOption: '',  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

        // How dates, times, and durations should be represented in the output.
        // This is ignored if value_render_option is
        // FORMATTED_VALUE.
        // The default dateTime render option is [DateTimeRenderOption.SERIAL_NUMBER].
        dateTimeRenderOption: '',  // TODO: Update placeholder value.

        auth: authClient,
      };

      sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchGet(request, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return;
        }

        // TODO: Change code below to process the `response` object:
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
      });
    });

    function authorize(callback) {
      // TODO: Change placeholder below to generate authentication credentials. See
      // https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/nodejs#step_3_set_up_the_sample
      //
      // Authorize using one of the following scopes:
      //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
      //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
      //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
      //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
      //   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'
      var authClient = null;

      if (authClient == null) {
        console.log('authentication failed');
        return;
      }
      callback(authClient);
    }
```

Comment: That's a false assumption. You need your credentials file to supply the client ID and secret. Your stored token file is simply the access token (and maybe a refresh token + refresh URI, depending on application type), and may or may not be valid for future API requests. While the access token is valid, your credentials aren't needed - but as soon as it is invalid, your credentials are needed to obtain a new access token. Please review the OAuth fundamentals.

Comment: I see. A follow-up - Once the access token is generated, what is the way to utilize it? Or what is the purpose of token.json?